# Android unit converter

Tags: java, android, unit-conversion

I am developing a unit converter application for Android. The application is working correctly, but my problem is with the optimization. Is there a way to somehow optimize the code?

I have different categories - speed, weight, length and so on, and for each of them I have separate activities. Here, for example, is the code for one of them:

```
public class Speed extends Activity {

    Map<Integer, Double> fromKmhMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromKmminMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromKmsMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromKnotMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromMphMap = new HashMap<>();
    private RadioGroup fromRadioGroup, toRadioGroup;
    private TextView from, to;
    private EditText fromInput, toOutput;
    private TextWatcher valueTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                checkFrom();
            } else {
                toOutput.setText("");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed);

        fromKmhMap.put(R.id.toKmh, 1.0);
        fromKmhMap.put(R.id.toKmmin, 0.01666666666667);
        fromKmhMap.put(R.id.toKms, 0.0002777777777778 );
        fromKmhMap.put(R.id.toKnot, 0.5399568034557);
        fromKmhMap.put(R.id.toMph, 0.6213711922373);

        fromKmminMap.put(R.id.toKmh, 60.0);
        fromKmminMap.put(R.id.toKmmin, 1.0);
        fromKmminMap.put(R.id.toKms, 0.01666666666667);
        fromKmminMap.put(R.id.toKnot, 32.39740820734);
        fromKmminMap.put(R.id.toMph, 37.28227153424);

        fromKmsMap.put(R.id.toKmh, 3600.0);
        fromKmsMap.put(R.id.toKmmin, 60.0);
        fromKmsMap.put(R.id.toKms, 1.0);
        fromKmsMap.put(R.id.toKnot, 1943.844492441);
        fromKmsMap.put(R.id.toMph, 2236.936292054);

        fromKnotMap.put(R.id.toKmh, 1.852);
        fromKnotMap.put(R.id.toKmmin, 0.03086666666667);
        fromKnotMap.put(R.id.toKms, 0.0005144444444444);
        fromKnotMap.put(R.id.toKnot, 1.0);
        fromKnotMap.put(R.id.toMph, 1.150779448024);

        fromMphMap.put(R.id.toKmh, 1.609344);
        fromMphMap.put(R.id.toKmmin, 0.0268224);
        fromMphMap.put(R.id.toKms, 0.00044704);
        fromMphMap.put(R.id.toKnot, 0.8689762419006);
        fromMphMap.put(R.id.toMph, 1.0);

        fromRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.fromSpeedGroup);
        toRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toSpeedGroup);
        from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedFrom);
        to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedTo);
        fromInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.speedInput);
        toOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.speedOutput);
        fromInput.addTextChangedListener(valueTextWatcher);

        fromRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                              checkFrom();
                }
            }
        });

        toRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                           checkFrom();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void fromKmh(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromKmhMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromKmmin(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromKmminMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromKms(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromKmsMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromKnot(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromKnotMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromMph(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromMphMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void checkFrom() {
        if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKmh) {
            fromKmh(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKmmin) {
            fromKmmin(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKms) {
            fromKms(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKnot) {
            fromKnot(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromMph) {
            fromMph(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another activity for weight measurements:

```
public class Weight extends Activity {

    Map<Integer, Double> fromGramMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromKilogramMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromMicrogramMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromMilligramMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromOunceMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromPoundMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Double> fromTroyOunceMap = new HashMap<>();

    private RadioGroup fromRadioGroup, toRadioGroup;
    private TextView from, to;
    private EditText fromInput, toOutput;
    private TextWatcher valueTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                checkFrom();
            } else {
                toOutput.setText("");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight);

        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 1.0);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.001);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 1000000.0);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 1000.0);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 0.03527396194958);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.002204622621849);
        fromGramMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 0.03215074656863);

        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 1000.0);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 1.0);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 1000000000.0);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 1000000.0);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 35.27396194958);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toPound, 2.204622621849);
        fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 32.15074656863);

        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 0.000001 );
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.000000001);
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 1.0);
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 0.001 );
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 0.000000035273);
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.00000000220);
        fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 0.0000000321);

        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 0.001  );
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.000001 );
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 1000.0);
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 1.0 );
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 0.00003527396194958 );
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.000002204622621849 );
        fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 0.00003215074656863 );

        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toGram, 28.349523125   );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.028349523125  );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 28349523.125 );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 28349.523125  );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 1.0 );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.0625  );
        fromOunceMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 0.9114583333333  );

        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toGram, 453.59237    );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.45359237   );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 453592370.0 );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 453592.37   );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 16.0 );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toPound, 1.0  );
        fromPoundMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 14.58333333333   );

        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toGram, 31.1034768     );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.0311034768    );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 31103476.8  );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 31103.4768    );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 1.097142857143  );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.06857142857143   );
        fromTroyOunceMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 1.0   );

        fromRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.fromWeightGroup);
        toRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toWeightGroup);
        from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightFrom);
        to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightTo);
        fromInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightInput);
        toOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightOutput);
        fromInput.addTextChangedListener(valueTextWatcher);

        fromRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    checkFrom();
                }
            }
        });

        toRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                   checkFrom();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void fromGram(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromGramMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromKilogram(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromKilogramMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromMicrogram(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromMicrogramMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromMilligram(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromMilligramMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromOunce(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromOunceMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromPound(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromPoundMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void fromTroyOunce(double valueToConvert)
    {
        toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * fromTroyOunceMap.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
    }

    private void checkFrom() {
        if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromGram) {
            fromGram(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKilogram) {
            fromKilogram(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromMicrogram) {
            fromMicrogram(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromMilligram) {
            fromMilligram(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromOunce) {
            fromOunce(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        }else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromPound) {
            fromPound(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        }else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromTroyOunce) {
            fromTroyOunce(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid copy-paste coding. Take for example this piece of code:

> ```
>     fromRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
>             if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
>                           checkFrom();
>             }
>         }
>     });
>
>     toRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
>             if (fromInput.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
>                        checkFrom();
>             }
>
>         }
>     });
> ```

The condition inside the two anonymous implementations was clearly copy-pasted. It would be better to create a helper method with the common logic, in particular:

```
private String normalizedInput(EditText input) {
    return input.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

And then rewrite the condition like this:

```
String normalized = normalizedInput(fromInput);
if (!normalized.isEmpty()) {
    checkFrom(normalized);
}
```

I did more than just extracted to a helper method:

- Replaced the `.length() > 0` with the more natural `!.isEmpty()`
- Pass the normalized string to `checkFrom`

This second point can be handy to prevent number parsing issues in the `checkFrom` method, or to make the number parsing more efficient thanks to the trimming.

Alternatively, as @Simon pointed out in a comment, you could create a single instance of `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` and set that on both the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` calls.

You can eliminate the duplication similarly from this code too:

> ```
> if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKmh) {
>     fromKmh(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
> } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKmmin) {
>     fromKmmin(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
> } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKms) {
>     fromKms(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
> } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromKnot) {
>     fromKnot(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
> } else if (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fromMph) {
>     fromMph(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
> }
> ```

That is, I suggest to assign the result of `Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString())` (or actually, `Double.parseDouble(normalized)` if you follow my recommendation earlier) to a variable, before entering the if-else chain.

Actually, it would be better to re-write this last if-else chain as a `switch (fromRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) { ... }`. I think that would be slightly more readable. (Thanks @Simon for the tip!)

Answer (score 6):

What you need is to use a **common base unit** that all your other units converts to.

For example, let's take a look at this:

```
fromGramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 1.0);
...
fromKilogramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 1000.0);
...
fromMicrogramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 0.000001 );
...
fromMilligramMap.put(R.id.toGram, 0.001  );
```

These are clearly related. 1 kilogram = 1000 gram = 1 000 000 milligram = 1 000 000 000 microgram. So instead of using multiple maps for `gram`, `kilogram`, `microgram` etc. Just use one base unit: Gram.

```
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toGram, 1.0);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toKilogram, 0.001);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toMicrogram, 1000000.0);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toMilligram, 1000.0);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toOunce, 0.03527396194958);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toPound, 0.002204622621849);
gramRatioMap.put(R.id.toTroyOunce, 0.03215074656863);
```

Now, to convert *from* Kilogram to gram, you can lookup the value for `R.id.toKilogram` and then use `1 / (that value)`. In this case, \$1 / 0.001 = 1000\$

Then, once you have converted to gram, you use your `gramRatioMap` as normal and convert to that specific unit.